# If $x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 +bx +1\geq0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, find maximum of $a^2+b^2$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, quartics

> Given that $x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 +bx +1$ is always greater than equal to $0$ for all $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R$, find $\max(a^2 + b^2)$.

What I did was to show that that above expression is equivalent to $$[x(x+a/2)]^2 + [(12-a^2)(x + 2b/(12-a^2))^2]/4  + (12-a^2 - b^2) /(12-a^2)\geq 0,$$
from this one case is that if $ 12-a^2\geq 0$, then the expression trivially is greater/equal zero, which given max of $a^2+b^2$ to be $12$, but what about if $12-a^2<=0$, then is max of $a^2+ b^2$ greater than 12 possible and what is the exact maximum ? Conclusion:  there are two such $f(x)$ for which maxima is attained those are $f(x) = x^4 -2√5x^3 + 3x^2+2√5x +1$ and other as said by achille hui.

Comment: I will do that from next time

Comment: The maximum is at least $40$ because $x^4 + 2\sqrt{5}x^3 + 3x^2 - 2\sqrt{5}x + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1)^2$ is non-negative for all $x$.

Comment: How to prove it , as such answer given was 40 ,i want to know how one gets that maximum from that 12-a^2<=0 case in my expression i got , for 12-a^2>=0 i got max to be 12 , can u show for the <=0 case max to be 40?

Comment: I didn't have a direct proof that $40$ is maximum. I get that configuration by computing the resultant of the polynomial and its derivative. That will give us the boundary ( in $(a,b)$ parameter space) where the condition "non-negative for all $x$" start to fail.

Comment: I tried this: As the equation has no real root the roots will be pairwise complex conjugate of each other. Also, their magnitudes will be pairwise multiplicative inverses of each other. Then using Vieta's theorem, we have to find maximum value. But I couldn't manage to get the max value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @achille hui  , nice way to get that function

Comment: @Paracetamol You may proceed to find the maximum of $a^3 + b^3$ which seems harder.

Comment: Yeah a bit more lengthh expressiom one would get of f(theta,phi) , but i will try , i think even power make it relatively easier than odd power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: This image contains the solution to your question]
I have started using MathJax but am not fluent in using it so posting the solution like this.

Comment: I am learning to use MathJax but typing this solution is very hectic as I am not fluent at it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Really gud way to solve it , i dont mind non latex sol , but do u think in my way , for 12-a^2<= 0 case , what could be the approach after that modified expression i got ?  Among the three terms in my expression first and third will be positive and the middle one would be negative , so what we need to do to ensure first + third sum always greater than or equal to middle term?

Comment: If you take cosθ=1 and cosϕ=−1 , you get a2=20 meaning that the maximum would be achieved when 12−a2<0 but the sum of 1st and 3rd quantities as well as the 2nd quantity are functions of x.So when you try to minimise the sum of 1st and 3rd, you don't know whether at that value the 2nd quantity is minimum so that you can make their sum positive to obtain a boundary condition in a and b. That is keeping us away from the correct answer. I think. –

Comment: I see so this is the best way to solve the problem ( ur method )?  My method will need much much work later on for simplification u mean for boundary condition?

Comment: One doubt regarding your solution also @ilove math that initial expression can be = 0 too for some x , that means there can exists real roots too isnt ? So why  take complex roots from start ?

Comment: Yes, a real root( say \alpha) may exist but as the expression is always greater than or equal to 0, that real root will have multiplicity 2. So let's say that the root z1 be the real root \alpha then, it's complex conjugate will also be \alpha making the multiplicity of \alpha= z1 equal to 2. Also real numbers are a subset of complex numbers so if you start by taking complex roots, there's no issue at all.

Comment: I see , one more thing in the sol above which step ensures that >=0 condition of the initial f(x) ? As such even if we not let that condition(assume its not there) we can assume roots to be complex which itself will include real too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129061/discussion-between-ilovemath-and-paracetamol).

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*: According to @achille hui's comment
$x^4 + 2\sqrt{5}x^3 + 3x^2 - 2\sqrt{5}x + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{5}\, x - 1)^2$, we give the following solution:

---

Let $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 + bx + 1$.

*Fact 1*: If $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
then $a^2 + b^2 \le 40$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, we have $a^2 + b^2 \le 40$.
On the other hand, if $a = 2\sqrt{5}, ~ b = -2\sqrt5$ with $a^2 + b^2 = 40$, we have $x^4 + 2\sqrt{5}\, x^3 + 3x^2 - 2\sqrt{5}\, x + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1)^2 \ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus, the maximum of $a^2 + b^2$ is $40$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*: We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: If $ab \ge 0$, since $f(1)  = a + b + 5 \ge 0$
and $f(-1) = - (a + b) + 5 \ge 0$, we have
$-5 \le a + b \le 5$ and thus
$a^2 + b^2 \le (a + b)^2 \le 25 < 40$.

**Case 2**: If $ab < 0$, WLOG, assume that $a > 0, ~ b < 0$ (otherwise, $a \to -a, ~ b \to -b, ~ x \to - x$).

Let $x_1 = \frac{-\sqrt5 + 3}{2} > 0$ and $x_2 = \frac{-\sqrt5 - 3}{2} < 0$.
(*Note*: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of $x^2 + \sqrt{5}\, x - 1 = 0$. See @achille hui's comment.)

From $f(x_1)\ge 0$, we have
$$b \ge -x_1^3 - ax_1^2 - 3x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1}. \tag{1}$$

From $f(x_2)\ge 0$, we have
$$b \le -x_2^3 - ax_2^2 - 3x_2 - \frac{1}{x_2}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), we have
$$-x_1^3 - ax_1^2 - 3x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1}
\le -x_2^3 - ax_2^2 - 3x_2 - \frac{1}{x_2}$$
which results in (*note*: $x_1 + x_2 = -\sqrt5, x_1x_2 = -1, x_1 - x_2 = 3$)
$$a \le \frac{x_1^3 - x_2^3 + 3x_1 - 3x_2 + \frac{1}{x_1} - \frac{1}{x_2}}{x_2^2 - x_1^2}
= \frac{x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + 3 - \frac{1}{x_1x_2}}{-(x_1 + x_2)} = 2\sqrt{5}.$$

Then, using $-x_1^3 - ax_1^2 - 3x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1} \le b < 0$ and $0 < a \le 2\sqrt5$, we have
\begin{align*}
 a^2 + b^2 &\le a^2 + \left(-x_1^3 - ax_1^2 - 3x_1 - \frac{1}{x_1}\right)^2\\
 &\le (2\sqrt{5})^2 + \left(x_1^3 + 2\sqrt{5}\cdot x_1^2 + 3x_1 + \frac{1}{x_1}\right)^2\\
 &= 40.
\end{align*}
*Note*: Here, we may use $x_1^2 + \sqrt{5}\, x_1 - 1 = 0$ to reduce the calculations. For example, $x_1^3 = -\sqrt{5}\, x_1^2  + x_1$.

We are done.

Comment: One thing i didnt quite get how u thought of getting f(3-√5/2) AND f(-3-√5/2 ) for case 2?not any other real numbers?

Comment: And achille hui comment uses derivative too for getting boundary conditions on a and b isnt ? In yours derivative wasnt used

Comment: @Paracetamol $\frac{-\sqrt5 + 3}{2}$ and $\frac{-\sqrt5 - 3}{2}$ are the two roots of $x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Paracetamol You can guess, at maximum of $a^2+b^2$, it should hold $x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 +bx +1 = (x^2 + px + q)^2$. If you guess that, you get $a = 2\sqrt{5}, b = -2\sqrt{5}$ etc. Although it is a guess, it is enough to motivate the solution.

Comment: Nice and the derivative achilles mentioned u didnt use isnt?

Comment: From that f(...) Part i meant why u use that if u didnt know from starting what function will get arrived finally , as such u have just f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 +3x^2 +bx +1 initially isnt?

Comment: @Paracetamol If we know achille hui's result $x^4 + 2\sqrt{5}x^3 + 3x^2 - 2\sqrt{5}x + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1)^2$, we just find the two roots of $x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1 = 0$, say $x_1, x_2$. We have $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = 0$ in his case $a = 2\sqrt5, b = 2\sqrt5$. For general $a, b$, we can go from $f(x_1) \ge 0$ and $f(x_2) \ge 0$ which gives conditions for $a, b$.  If we don't know achille hui's result, I will guess, when $a^2 + b^2$ is maximized, it should admit $x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 +bx +1 = (x^2 + px + q)^2$ which actually gives $a = 2\sqrt5, b= -2\sqrt5$.

Comment: Fully understood thanks River Li

Comment: @Paracetamol You are welcome.